# NullPointerException: @Autowired does not set field

Tags: java, spring

I am learning SPRING and this is not web application code; I am getting NLP while using @Autowired annotation in field level.

Q1) Please help what is wrong? 
Q2) If i have  @Scope annotation at the class level; do i still need at XML bean level?

```
@Controller
@Scope(value = BeanDefinition.SCOPE_SINGLETON)
public class StreamingController implements psConsolePortListener.Implementation{

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("scMgr")
    private StreamingControllerManager streamingMgr = null;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        logger.info("StreamingController testing");
        XmlBeanFactory factory = new XmlBeanFactory (new ClassPathResource(BEAN_FILE)); 
        StreamingController obj = (StreamingController) factory.getBean("streamingController"); 
        obj.streamingMgr.test();
    }

}


@Service
@Scope(value = BeanDefinition.SCOPE_SINGLETON)
@Qualifier("scMgr")
public class StreamingControllerManager {
    /** Logger */
    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(StreamingControllerManager.class);

    private StreamingControllerManager(){
        logger.info("StreamingControllerManager is called!!");
    }

    public void test(){
        logger.info("StreamingControllerManager test!!");
    }
}
```

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans>
    <context:annotation-config />
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.xxx.streamingController"/>
    <bean id="scMgr" class="com.xxx.streamingController.StreamingControllerManager"> 
    </bean>
    <bean id="streamingController" class="com.xxx.streamingController.StreamingController"> 
    </bean>
</beans>
```

Output:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.pactolus.streamingController.StreamingController.main(
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an `ApplicationContext` instead of a `BeanFactory`.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    logger.info("StreamingController testing");
    ApplicationContext ctx = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext(BEAN_FILE);
    StreamingController obj = (StreamingController) ctx.getBean("streamingController"); 
    obj.streamingMgr.test();
}
```

Also remove `<context:annotation-config />` that is already impllied by `<context:component-scan />` and remove the bean declarations. You are using component-scanning so no need to declare the beans.

Basically leaving you with.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans>
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.xxx"/>
</beans>
```

Comment: Thanks!! you mean to say it is drawback of BeanFactory ??

Comment: No `BeanFactory` and `ApplicationContext` are different things (a `BeanFactory` only creates beans and doesn't do anything with `Bean(Factory)PostProcessors` whereas the `ApplicationContext` does). I strongly suggest a read of chapter 3 of the spring reference guide.